# Is there a way to run DebugDiag Analysis from the command line?

Tags: debugging, automation, windbg, debugdiag

Is there a way to invoke [DebugDiag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/) Analysis from the command line? I've tried this:

`DebugDiag.Analysis.exe "C:\dumps\oops.dmp"`

But it only started up the GUI (with `oops.dmp` added).

What I am looking for is something more like this:

`DebugDiag.Analysis.exe -dump "C:\dumps\oops.dmp" -out "C:\results\oops-DebugDiag.mht" -anaylsis "CrashHangAnalysis,MemoryAnalysis"`

Then this should run, without showing any GUI.

Usecase: We're running our crash dump analysis fully automated with [SuperDump](https://github.com/Dynatrace/superdump). Adding DebugDiag `.mht` reports automatically would be really nice.

Can this be done? Is there any documentation on DebugDiag commandline options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DebugDiag does not explose a CLI out of the box.

However, it exposes a class named `DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer` via `DebugDiag.DotNet.dll` which is available in the installation directory of DebugDiag. Here is it's documentation:

```
/// <summary>
/// The NetAnalyzer object is used to determine available analysis scripts, add data files, and start an analysis.  
/// This object is used internally by the DebugDiag Analysis user interface to manage analysis rules.  
/// End users can use this object to develop their own rules, batch files, or GUI's to manage data analysis.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <example>
/// <code language="cs">
/// using (NetAnalyzer analyzer = new NetAnalyzer())
/// {
///     //In this example I'm referencing a dll module that has the prebuild rules that ship with debugdiag 
///     analyzer.AddAnalysisRulesToRunList(@"C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\AnalysisRules\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.dll", false);
///
///     List&lt;AnalysisRuleInfo&gt; analysisRules = analyzer.AnalysisRuleInfos;
///
///     Console.WriteLine("The available rules on the analyzer are: \n\r\n\r");
///
///     foreach(AnalysisRuleInfo ruleInfo in analysisRules)
///     {
///          Console.WriteLine(ruleInfo.DisplayName);
///     }
/// }
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// </remarks>
```

So, basically it's possible to use this API to automate it. Here are two projects, which currently use it like this:

- https://github.com/hivanovms/DumpAnalyzer
- https://github.com/Dynatrace/superdump/tree/master/src/SuperDump.DebugDiag